# JAVA_HOME no change for ionic run android

Tags: java, macos, ionic-framework, java-home

I am developing in Ionic 4.
I am using mac Mojave, and according to `java -version`, I am using `1.8.0_201`, and `$ JAVA_HOME` also points to `1.8.0_201`.
However, when running ionic cordova run android, it gives me an android version error, because it indicates that I am using the `JAVA_HOME` of java 11.

**Where is `JAVA_HOME` specified for ionic?**

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

$JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Error ...

> cordova build android --device
> Android Studio project detected
> ANDROID_HOME=/Users/antoniodelgado/Library/Android/sdk
> JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
> studio

Comment: By any chance, did you change JAVA_HOME in one terminal and running `run android` in other terminal which was opened before changing the path? Try re-opening the terminal.

Comment: In all the terminals that I open I echo $ JAVA_HOME points to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home, but when I try to generate the apk, in the same terminal or another, it tells me ionic that the JAVA_HOME corresponds to jdk-11.0.2.